# C# Deedle Dataframe ReplaceColumn <MIssing> values

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure this one out. First off I'm completely new to Deedle so forgive me if I ask a dumb question here.

So I have a parent Frame that I'm filtering resulting in a sub frame

```
var subFrame = parentFrame.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.GetAs<string>("ColA") == "ValueA" && kvp.Value.GetAs<string>("ColB") == "ValueB");

var subCol = subFrame.GetColumn<decimal>("ColDecimal1");
subCol = subFrame.GetColumn<decimal>("ColDecimal2");

parentFrame.ReplaceColumn("ColDecimal1", subCol);
```

When I do this it almost gives me my desired results. The column values do align with the key values of the parent row however, the keys that did not match what was initially fetch via the subFrame/filtering have a "ColDecimal1" value of . I know this is what is stated in the Deedle documentation but I'm trying to find a work around to this. My preference is possibly getting some examples in C# vs F#, F# is a bit foreign to me so it's been difficult to follow.

Anways, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subFrame` only has data for some of the rows (as specified by your filter). `ReplaceColumn` will replace a column, adding `<Missing>` for all row keys for which the new column does not have values, so that is why you're seeing what you are seeing.

If you would like to get a result with the new values for rows that were selected by the filter, but the old value for all other rows, you can do this using `Zip` and `Select`.

For example, say I have two series:

```
let parentCol = series [1 => 1.0; 2 => 2.0; 3 => 3.0]
let subCol = series [1 => 1.1 ]
```

The `subCol` has data just for key `1`. Now, I want to replace the value `1.0` in `parentCol` with the value from `subCol` to do this in F#, you'd write (assuming there are no missing values in `parentCol`):

```
parentCol.Zip(subCol, JoinKind.Left).SelectValues(fun (v1, v2) ->
  if v2.HasValue then v2.Value else v1.Value
)
```

The only thing different in C# is that you access tuple elements using `Item1` and `Item2` and a different lambda syntax. I did not test this, but it should be:

```
parentCol.Zip(subCol, JoinKind.Left).SelectValues(v =>
  v.Item2.HasValue ? v.Item2.Value : v.Item1.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is what I was looking for. I was tinkering with the Zip method before and just couldn't get it to work, with your example I was able to get what I needed.